# ArcGIS JavaScript api Map update-end stops firing

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis-js-api

We have a complex web mapping app using arcgis JavaScript api. The following code is used to inform the ui that the map layers are loaded:

```
on(map,"update-end",function(){
    //emit event to ui module
});

map.addLayers(layers);
```

The application frequently adds and removes map layers. However occasionally something is going wrong and although layers get added the update-end event doesn't get fired, despite the layers completing load. After this happens the event wont fire again unless the app reloads.

Does anyone have an idea under what conditions this may occur? How can we prevent the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I usually put my `map.on("update-end", endUpdateMap);` sentence after any map.addlayer() in the same javascript where you are defining your layers. It works fine for me.

```
map.on("update-end", endUpdateMap);

function endUpdateMap(error) {
         esri.hide(loading);
         map.enableMapNavigation();
         map.disableDoubleClickZoom();
         map.showZoomSlider();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, I think there is actually a bug in the JSAPI. If you remove a layer whilst it is updating then it actually breaks the "update-start" and "update-end" events, they stop firing completely. I will try and put a test case together at some point but I found with a slow drawing layer, like an image service, the issue was very prevalent.

Anyway, I had to think of a way around it and this is what I came up with:

```
this.layer.setVisibility(false); // set invisible first to ensure spinner stop
this.map.removeLayer(this.layer);
```